# Adding and Updating records with EmberData

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I may be being daft but the Ember.js's Model section seems to really only cover GETing data from a REST server but not adding a new one or updating an existing one. I did notice the following:

- [Pushing Records into a Store](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/) -brings up `store.push()` but the coverage is brief and the use case is not practical for most web applications.
- [TRANSITION.md](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#transaction-is-gone-save-individual-records) - this vital reference for folks getting into the ember-data 1.0 beta has a section which discusses the removal of transactions and thereby covers this topic inadvertently

Can anyone suggest some other examples of adding or updating data using Ember Data's 1.0-beta codebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Getting Started" section of the Ember guides has the basic info about creating and updating records.

#### Creating

http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/

```
var post = this.store.createRecord('post'{ title : "My New Post"});
post.save();
```

#### Updating

http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/

```
var post = this.get('content');
post.set("title", "My New Title");
post.save();
```

In both cases calling `save()` on the model is what "commits" the changes.  You can also call `rollback()` if you want to revert.

Comment: Ahhh good place for it too. As I've been drip feeding my Ember knowledge over time I now look more in the reference section and not the "getting started" section as I falsely assume I've already gotten started. :^)

Comment: I've done exactly the same thing a hundred times.  I'm finally remembering to at least skim the "getting started" section every once in a while when I hit a problem.

Comment: save: function (channel) {
            channel.save() //calls delete instead of put. 
        }, Any idea whats happening?

Comment: At some point you're probably calling `channel.delete()`. Calling `delete` on a record must be followed by a call to `save` to flush it to the server.